# How to make click event handler functions with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to add an event listener for clicks but it's saying that classList doesn't exist on type EventTarget.

```
class UIModal extends React.Component<Props> {
    handleClick = (e: Event) => {
        if ((e.target as EventTarget).classList.contains('modal-mask')) {
            this.props.close();
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="modal-mask">
                <div className="modal">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Improved solution todo - https://rjzaworski.com/2018/10/typescript-event-handlers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try `e.target as Element`?

Answer (score 0):

`e.target` should be `e.currentTarget`

There's a bit of a discussion about this here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/299

Comment: It should be target unless if he's doing event delegation (ie: attaching handler to a top level div, and wanting to work with the element that triggered it) (currentTarget will be the element that listener was attached to)